# Module is reported to be missing, but it's present and active

Tags: 8

I have a field type that have some default dependencies, such as Ctools and Views.
I need the *Able Player* module, which is for Drupal 7.
I installed this module, configured the *Able Player* libraries and checked that all is OK in the report section.
This module is installed in /sites/all/modules/able_player folder.
In my info file I wrote the following line.

```
dependencies[] = able_player.
```

When I attempt to activate my module, Drupal says that the *Able Player* module is missing, but it is present and active.

For a test, I tried some other modules, such as the *jQuery Update* module, and it works fine.

Why does Drupal say the module is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not install a Drupal 7 module on Drupal 8. That's not possible.

The module needs to be converted to Drupal 8. Drupal reports the module as missing because the .info file is now info.yml, so Drupal does not find a able_player.info.yml file anywhere and correctly reports the module as missing.

Comment: I solved by adding ableplayer scripts on my field view function, by using drupal_add_js and drupal_add_css functions. Now it works!